# Remotely hosted HTTPS Images not displaying in Safari 4.1.3 on Macs

Tags: safari, https

Working with a ticketing system site that must be accessed via HTTPS at https://www.threestages.net

Our images are hosted elsewhere ( https://wserver.flc.losrios.edu/~vapa/) and also accessed via HTTPS.

We have multiple reports that Safari 4.1.3 on Macs is not displaying the images.  We have no reports of this behavior from any other browser or platform.

Any one have any notion what that would be about?

Thanks for any thoughts,

JG

Comment: Can you view the image in Safari directly (not by going through the ticketing system)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  Email sent to get user to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Safari has an issue with the SSL Cert at https://wserver.flc.losrios.edu/

http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html let me know that

> The certificate is not trusted in all
>   web browsers. You may need to install
>   an Intermediate/chain certificate to
>   link it to a trusted root certificate.

Thanks for looking at this.  Valuable lessons learned:

1. Even if 4 out of 5 browsers accept an SSL Cert that doesn't mean they all do
2. Just because the sysadmin says it's not his problem/mistake doesn't make it so!
3. Check everything.  Then repeat.